# Typahead Search - why is my React State one step behind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, autocomplete

I'm building a typahead search that listens to the state of the input and renders a list of search results that include the input. But my function checkTypaheadMatches, which sets the state for the results that match the input state, is one step behind. For some reason, in this function, the input state is one step behind.

However, if I console log the input state OUTSIDE of the function, it is not behind. I'm confused because I thought I had my onChange function setup currently on my input. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Here is my App.jsx (it renders the Header component, which renders my SearchBar component.)

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Header from "./components/Header"

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const validRecipTypes = ["medical doctor", "doctor of osteopathy", "doctor of podiatric medicine", "physician assistant", "nurse practitioner", "certified registered nurse anesthetist", "doctor of dentistry"]

  const [recipTypeQ, setRecipTypeQ] = useState("")
  const [typaheadMatches, setTypaheadMatches] = useState(validRecipTypes)
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])

  const checkTypaheadMatches = () => {
    let matches = []
    for (const recipient_type of validRecipTypes) {
        if (recipient_type.includes(recipTypeQ.toLowerCase())) {
            matches.push(recipient_type)
        }
    }

    console.log("Am I fixed yet?: ", recipTypeQ) // <-- this is one step behind!

    setTypaheadMatches(matches)
  }

  const onRecipTypeQChange = (e) => {
    setRecipTypeQ(e.target.value, checkTypaheadMatches()) // <-- did I do this right?
  }

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    // search function
  }

  return <>
    <div className="App w-screen p-8">
      <Header 
        onRecipTypeQChange={onRecipTypeQChange} 
        handleSearch={handleSearch} 
        recipTypeQ={recipTypeQ}
        typaheadMatches={typaheadMatches}
        setTypaheadMatches={setTypaheadMatches}
        />
      <Outlet context={[
        searchResults, setSearchResults,
        validRecipTypes
      ]} />
    </div>
  </>
}

export default App
```

My SearchBar.jsx

```
import TypaheadMatchesDisplay from "./TypaheadMatchesDisplay";

const SearchBar = ({onRecipTypeQChange, handleSearch, typaheadMatches}) => {
    return <div className="flex items-center gap-6 px-4 border-2 border-green-500 relative">
        <label htmlFor="search_form" className="text-lg font-medium">Search:</label>

        <form data-test="search-form" onSubmit={handleSearch} method="GET" id="search_form">

            <input onChange={onRecipTypeQChange} type="text" id="recipTypeQ" name="recipTypeQ" required mindocLength="1" placeholder="search by recipient type..."/>

            <TypaheadMatchesDisplay typaheadMatches={typaheadMatches}/>

            <button data-test="submit-button" type="submit" form="search_form" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}

export default SearchBar
```

Answer (score 1):

It is one step behind because you are checking in the wrong place. The job of the `checkTypaheadMatches` function is to find the matches, but not to set the value. So you should check the value of `recipTypeQ` after setting it.

You may not need to call the `checkTypaheadMatches` in `useState` set function

```
const onRecipTypeQChange = (e) => {
  checkTypaheadMatches();
  setRecipTypeQ(e.target.value);
  // check the value of recipTypeQ here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion brk -- I tried that but my typahead results are still one step behind. I do need recipTypeQ to be up to date in the checkTypaheadMatches function because it (checkTypahead) needs to read recipTypeQ's state accurately in order to return the correct results. It's returning incorrect results because it is one step behind.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I had to move the checkTypaheadMatches function into a useEffect hook. This is what I did:

```
 useEffect(checkTypaheadMatches, [recipTypeQ])

  const onRecipTypeQChange = (e) => {
    setRecipTypeQ(e.target.value)
  }
```